# How to query all Identity Module's registered info?

Tags: identity

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66228220/how-to-query-all-current-polkadot-accounts-with-polkadot-js) told me how to query balance info of all accounts. Now I would like to query the [Identity Module](https://github.com/paritytech/substrate/tree/master/frame/identity)'s information of all accounts on Kusama chain (such as Legal Name, Twitter handle and so on).

I thought there must be some way to access registered information using polkadot-api, not web UI. The information seems to be inserted by [line 364](https://github.com/paritytech/substrate/blob/master/frame/identity/src/lib.rs#L364)

```
            <IdentityOf<T>>::insert(&sender, id);
```

But I could not dig deeper. Thank you for your help in advance.

Answer (score 3):

There is no difference between retrieving the [entries for any map](https://polkadot.js.org/docs/api/start/api.query.other#map-keys--entries), the format is exactly the same as in the answer you linked.

In this case, use [identityOf](https://polkadot.js.org/docs/substrate/storage#identityofaccountid32-optionpalletidentityregistration) which is a map -

```js
const all = await api.query.identity.identityOf.entries()

for (let i = 0; i < all.length; i++) {
  const [key, value] = all[i]

  console.log(
    "accountId=", key.args[0].toHuman(), 
    ", value=", JSON.stringify(value.toHuman(), null, 2)
  )
}
```

You can paste the code on the [Polkadot.js Playground](https://polkadot.js.org/apps/#/js) to verify the result.

Comment: Thank you very much. In my environment, your code worked except that 'console.log("accountId=" + key.args[0].toHuman() + ", value=" + value.toHuman())' outputs ' <snip> value=[object Object]'  When I changed it to 'console.log(value.toHuman())', it worked. Concatenation of string and value.toHuman() may have some unexpected behavior unknown to me.

Comment: When I changed it to 'console.log("accountId=" + key.args[0].toHuman() + ", value=" + JSON.stringify(value.toHuman(), null, 4));', it showed the value in full details. Thank you again.

Comment: Sorry for multiple comment, some of the value were still not fully converted into human-readable format, such as [Array] [Array] below. I thought it was due to JSON issue but could not resolve. 
{
  judgements: [],
  deposit: '49,999,999,500',
  info: {
    additional: [ [Array], [Array] ],
    display: 'None',
    legal: 'None',
    web: 'None',
    riot: 'None',
    email: 'None',
    pgpFingerprint: null,
    image: 'None',
    twitter: 'None'
  }
}

Comment: Edited the (untested) code with JSON.stringify to serialize object.